# angularjs component controller not passing initial binding value to directive in template (summernote)

Tags: angularjs, summernote

I have this rather simple angularjs component that has an optional height binding:

```js
"use strict";

angular
  .module("app")
  .component("myComp", getComp());

function getComp() {
  return {
    bindings: getBindings(),
    template: getTemplate(),
    require: "ngModel",
    controller,
  };
}

function getBindings() {
  return {
    height: "<?",
    noExternalFonts: "<?",
    ngModel: "=",
  }
}

function getTemplate() {
  return `<summernote height="$ctrl.height" ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel" config="$ctrl.options"></summernote>`
}

function controller(chSummernoteService) {
  const ctrl = this;
  ctrl.chSummernoteService = chSummernoteService;
  ctrl.$onInit = onInit.bind(ctrl);
}

function onInit() {
  const ctrl = this;
  ctrl.options = ctrl.chSummernoteService.getOptions({
    noExternalFonts: ctrl.noExternalFonts,
  });
}
```

The problem is, when I call it, the height is being ignored by summernote, the directive in the template, even tho the other two attributes, `ng-model` and `options` work fine.

```js
<my-comp height="400" ng-model="$ctrl.someOtherCtrl></my-comp>
```

I also checked replated the `$ctrl.height` in the template with a hard coded number and that DOES work.

Is that some angularjs quirk I'm unaware of? (I'm new to angularjs, coming from React)

Or is that a bug in the summernote directive maybe?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out the angular-summernote src and it appears to be bugged. Their controller is improperly written such that it reads the raw string value of the `height` attribute no matter what, so it's literally interpreted as `"$ctrl.height"`. It's also written in such a way that it'll still read the raw value even if you try to force it in between interpolation bindings, i.e. `height="{{ $ctrl.height }}"` won't work either.

Luckily, the `config` attribute is being parsed properly, and according to the documentation the height can be specified as a property within that instead. So remove the `height` attribute from your element and within your `onInit` function, add the height property to your config object:

```
ctrl.options.height = ctrl.height;
```

Comment: Sweet!! Can't believe I didn't check if height is supported in options ‍♀️ You could PR `angular-summernote` if you have the fix inhand!

Comment: I would but the last commit was over 4 years ago and I don't actually use summernote, plus this is a good workaround